# Dygraph is not working

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I was trying to use Dygraphs in web application. Please see below simple code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7; IE=EmulateIE9">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>MyHtml.html</title>
    <!--[if IE]>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/excanvas.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/rgbcolor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dygraphs.com/dygraph-combined.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dygraph-combined.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dygraph.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/CanvasRenderingContext2D.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="graphdiv"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      g = new Dygraph(
      document.getElementById("graphdiv"), "Date,Temperature\n" + "2008-05-07,75\n" + "2008-05-08,70\n" + "2008-05-09,80\n");
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

If i include the line 
type="text/javascript" src="http://dygraphs.com/dygraph-combined.js"
with the scripts it works fine in firefox and chrome and it wont work in IE, it gives error like 'CanvasRenderingContext2D' is undefined. If i download the dygraph-combined.js and include it in my web application and access it by giving path, it wont work in all three browsers, it gives an error message Dygraph not defined. Please help me. I want to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 2):

You should only need to include dygraph-combined.js, whether from your website or your own site. Did you include excanvas.js on your site? This could explain why it's not working in IE8.

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be that scripts which are in `/js/...` are not accessible for any of your browser.

- It explains why in the case you refer to remote `dygraph-combined.js`, only IE doesn't work - it needs `excanvas.js` referenced from `/js/...`
- In the case you downloaded `dygraph-combined.js` and replace the remote reference to `/js/...` then no browser works as they can't access the `/js/dygraph-combined.js`

Check accessibility of `/js/dygraph-combined.js` and `/js/excanvas.js`. Should there be the reference without leading slash e.g.: `js/dygraph-combined.js`?

And as previously mentioned, remove all other script references (except dygraph-combined and excanvas.js). Dygraph-combined already contains everything in one file and excanvas is needed for IE.